# How can I let the keras model prediction accuracy same as model test accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have training the CNN model these days.
The datasets which I use are 'fashion mnist' dataset.
I want to train the model that can predict the picture that I collected correctly.
I split my data into:
(train,validation,test) = (55000,5000,10000)

```py
# Further break training data into train / validation sets (# put 5000 into validation set and keep remaining 55,000 for train)
(x_train, x_valid) = x_train[5000:], x_train[:5000] 
(y_train, y_valid) = y_train[5000:], y_train[:5000]
```

The code that used to predict my picture in the file on my desktop.

```py
file_dir = '/Users/yan/Desktop/data/'
data = []
for n in os.listdir(file_dir):
    if(n.lower().endswith(('.png','.jpg','.jpeg'))):
        data_dir = file_dir + n

        im = Image.open(data_dir)
        im = im.convert('L')
        im = im.resize((28,28),PIL.Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        image_list = []
        for x in range(28):
            scanline_list = []
            for y in range(28):
                pixel = im.getpixel((y,x))
                pixel = 255.0-pixel
                pixel = pixel/255.0
                scanline_list.append(pixel)
            image_list.append(scanline_list)

        arr1 = np.array(image_list).reshape((1,28,28,1))

        classes=list(fashion_mnist_labels.values())
        predictions = classes[np.argmax(model.predict(arr1))]
        print(n + "預測為：" + predictions)
```

(預測為 means 'predict')
The accuracy of the model is about 89%~90%.
When I use the dataset which is prepared by myself, the accuracy of the prediction is only about 45%~50%.
I couldn't understand why the accuracy of the model is around 90%, the result of predict my dataset is so terrible.
Why it can't reach to 90%?

The predictions:
(which I have ticked are correct)
[image]
[image]
[image]
The accuracy:
[image]

This is my model.
[image]
Part of the dataset that I used to predict:
[image]

Please let me know if you know the method to solve it!
Thank you!!!

Comment: There is no point in reposting the same question that was closed, this is a problem of generalization which is not a programming problem.

Comment: there is something wrong on your preprocessing probably, but I agree on what @Dr.Snoopy said, please don't do this

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy  I'm sorry about reposting the same question, I reposted it because the question was closed and I don't know how to reopened it . Also I'm new here, I do not know much rules here. So if I 'm in the same condition, the closed question still can be commented by the person who has commented on it? Or what can I do when my question is closed? Thank you so much.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I'm sorry, I won't do it next time.